# How can I refactor this code out?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have the following bits of code, scattered throughout my application.  I'd really like to boilerplate it, and place it in either a static class, or some utility set of classes so I don't have all this duplication.

However, the small bits of the function are unique in such a way that I don't know how to refactor it.

```
private void callResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
                HttpWebResponse response;

                // End the get response operation
                response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
                Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
                string responseData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                streamResponse.Close();
                streamReader.Close();
                response.Close();


                ExpectedResponseType regResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpectedResponseType>(responseData);

                if (regResponse.ok == "0")
                {
                    //error - handle the msg
                    //whether the user not loggin or not exist 
                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {

                         MessageBox.Show(CustomErrorMessage);

                    });

                }
                else
                {
                    //check the variables unique to the ExpectedResponseType and do Stuff here;                      


                }
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                // Error treatment
                // ...

                Debug.WriteLine("error " + e);
            }
```

I am most curious how to pass in "ExpectedResponseType", such that it might be any Class, (i.e., is there a way to pass in T?)  or possibly how to fire events that can then be executed by the UI thread and handled appropriately.

Thanks.

edit:  "ExpectedResponseType" or "T"  is a large collection of classes for each type of server call.  For example I have LoginResponse, RegisterResponse, GetFilesResponse, UpdateResponse,  DownloadResponse, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I have removed earlier example as it would not work with the delegate signature.

In order to handle the checking of the parameters specific to the type T you will need to add a little abstraction, the cleanest way is probably to wrap your code in a templated class that allows the registration of a delegate for handling the checking, I'm sure this is a specific pattern but cannot recall which one:

```
public class ResponseHandler<T>
{
    public ResponseHandler(Action<T> typeSpecificCheckFunction)
    {
        this.CheckVariables = typeSpecificCheckFunction;
    }
    Action<T> CheckVariables;
    public void callResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        // stuff
        T regResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseData);
        CheckVariables(response);
        // stuff
    }
}
```

In response to you question about handling a large variety of T, perhaps the cleaned up code above clears it up, if not then this is what generics are for - provided you know what you are expecting in each case.  So for each type you were expecting you would call it something along the lines of:

```
var handler = new ResponseHandler<ExpectedResponseType>( response => 
                        {
                             // code to check your response properties here 
                        });

xxx.RegisterResponseCallback(handler.callResponseCallback);
```

Comment: Ok, something I'm confused about here, is how do I allow for a large variety of T?   do I have to create an interface, or is there some other C# technique?

Comment: T here can be anything at all - it's an unconstrained type parameter. You might want to read up on generic classes in C#.

Comment: @Bob - do you mean that ExpectedResponseType is unknown? in other words your real question is how to call a generic method with an unknown type?  That is not possible - it is precisely what generics are intended to avoid.

Comment: No, I'm a bit confused on how I Define  the function/class to expect a generic.  When I type "T" I am told that it is an unknown type or variable.

I want to pass in the Type.  The same way that a List is able to accept any Type and work.

Comment: This is too tricky to guess what is going on - you need to update your question with the piece of code you are having trouble with.